# Combine anonymization of IPs in Apache logs using anonip.py with log rotation using Cronolog

Tags: ubuntu, logging, apache2, anonymize

I sure hope I've come to the right place.

I want to anonymize IP addresses in log files (see [here](https://www.privacyfoundation.ch/de/service/anonip.html)) while also rotating log files with Cronolog on Ubuntu 16.04.

This is a slight derivation of my current CustomLog entry:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/anonip.py --output |/usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/test.mydomain/log/%Y-%m/access_%d.log" combined
```

It does work if I omit cronolog, but not with it. Does anyone know how to make this work? Alternatives are also appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a logging pipe composed of multiple commands with:

```
CustomLog "|$ /usr/bin/python2.7 /var/www/anonip.py | /usr/bin/cronolog /var/www/test.mydomain/log/%Y-%m/access_%d.log" combined
```

(omitted option *--output* which would write the anonymized log to a file instead of *stdout*)

With `|$ ...` instead of `| ...` Apache2's `CustomLog` starts a shell with can start multiple commands in a pipe instead of a single command as explained in [Apache2 Manual - Piped Logs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped).